# How to use routing resolves on ajax calls

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and there is virtually no documentation on routing resolves .

1.How Do we use resolves?

2.I need to run an ajax call before the page load. How do I do that if the ajax calls are in the service.js?
3. Can I redirect to another page if the ajax call fails or if I do not get favourable objects in the success of the ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a resolve-block with a route you can do

```
        var dataResolve = ['someDependency', function(someDependency) {
            return someDependency.someThingAsync();
        }];
```

Sets up the resolve-objekt and injects stuff into it.

```
        when('/my/url', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/myTemplate.html',
                controller: 'MyCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    data: dataResolve
                }
        })
```

Sets up the resolve for the route. The controller can then take `data` into its constructor function.

As for cancelling the route, I am not sure.

Comment: Hi Thank you. If i need to use the URL currently or the routePram in the resolve then how to do it ?

Comment: If you look at the docs, there's a `$routeChangeStart` event broadcasted when the route changes, but it's only sent once the dependencies are resolved so I'm not sure if that is possible. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route